# Grid view export beforeFooter in Yii2 Kartik

Tags: widget, export, yii2

I use the kartik widget from the following site,

GridView: http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo

can someone help me, how to get the export before Footer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just change the template there is an `{export}` marker where the export button will be rendered to.
Examples given:
http://demos.krajee.com/grid#layout-templates